# how to make multiple table join in firebase in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have multiple table's that i wanted to join based on the id of the main table.
this is my script.

```
var bookinghistory = database.ref('bookingHistory');
var hospital = database.ref('hospitals');
var client = database.ref('clients');
var patient = database.ref('patients');

bookinghistory.once('value', function (snapshot) {
        var promises = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {

            var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var fk = snapshot.child(childKey).val();

            var myhospital = hospital.child(childSnapshot.val().hospital_fk).once('value');
            var myclient = client.child(childSnapshot.val().client_fk).once('value');
            var mypatient = patient.child(childSnapshot.val().patient_id).once('value');

            promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                 myhospital.then(docResult => {
                    resolve({         
                        childKey: childKey,
                        bookhistory: fk,
                        hospital: docResult
                    });
                }).catch(reason => {
                    reject(reason);
                 });
             }));
            promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                 myclient.then(docResult => {
                    resolve({         
                        client: docResult
                    });
                }).catch(reason => {
                    reject(reason);
                 });
             }));
            promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                 mypatient.then(docResult => {
                    resolve({         
                        patient: docResult
                    });
                }).catch(reason => {
                    reject(reason);
                 });
             }));
       }));
});
Promise.all(promises).then(function(snapshots) {
        var dataSet = [];
         snapshots.forEach(function(hospital) {

            dataSet.push({
                childKey: hospital.childKey, 
                booth: hospital.booth,
                hospital:hospital.hospital,
                client:hospital.client,
                patient:hospital.patient

            });

        });
        res.json(dataSet);
    });
```

and this is the result of my script.

```
[
    {
        "childKey": "-L2snm8lhye",
        "hospital": {
            "address": "Rizal Drive cor. ",
            "city": "",
            "createdAt": "2018-01-14 23:01:32",
            "deletedAt": "",
            "latitude": "14.554928",
            "longitude": "1115",
            "name": "St. Luke's Medical Center - Global City",
            "province": "",
            "updatedAt": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "client": {
            "createdAt": "2018-01-15",
            "firstName": "",
            "identifier": "+63933000000",
            "lastName": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "patient": {
            "birthdate": "1993-01-15",
            "client_fk": "qFUJT05B19NgQ2",
            "createdAt": "2018-01-15 15:02:13",
            "deletedAt": "",
            "firstName": "Eric Christian",
            "gender": "1",
            "lastName": "Odulio",
            "updatedAt": ""
        }
    }
]
```

what i wanted is client,patient data show be after the hospital array.. what happen is it goes outside.. this is the json that i wanted to be returned.. is there any way to do this?.

```
[
    {
        "childKey": "-L2snm8lhye",
        "hospital": {
            "address": "Rizal Drive cor. ",
            "city": "",
            "createdAt": "2018-01-14 23:01:32",
            "deletedAt": "",
            "latitude": "14.554928",
            "longitude": "1115",
            "name": "St. Luke's Medical Center - Global City",
            "province": "",
            "updatedAt": ""
        }
        "client": {
            "createdAt": "2018-01-15",
            "firstName": "",
            "identifier": "+63933000000",
            "lastName": ""
        }
        "patient": {
            "birthdate": "1993-01-15",
            "client_fk": "qFUJT05B19NgQ2",
            "createdAt": "2018-01-15 15:02:13",
            "deletedAt": "",
            "firstName": "Eric",
            "gender": "1",
            "lastName": "Odulio",
            "updatedAt": ""
        }
   }
]
```

Comment: might help you https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/10/queries-part-1-common-sql-queries.html#join

Comment: @PeterHaddad i tried it and i got an error...$ is not defined..

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did to get the answer that i want.. just push once then call the tables based on the main child id.. so this is how it looks like

```
promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   myhospital.then(hospitalResult => {
       myclient.then(clientResult => {
             mypatient.then(patientResult => {
                 resolve({         
                      childKey: childKey,
                      bookhistory: fk,
                      hospital: hospitalResult,
                      client: clientResult,
                      patient: patientResult
                 });
             });
       });
   }).catch(reason => {
       reject(reason);
   });
}));
```